# An OR operator causes two different behaviors

Tags: php

I am unable to understand why two conditions containing the same values do not return the same result twice.

Look at the variable content :

```
$quantity = 1;
var_dump(!$cart = true);
var_dump(!$product = false);
var_dump($quantity <= 0);
--------
Output : bool(false) bool(true) bool(false)
```

Based on those boolean, I expect the following condition will return `TRUE` :

```
$quantity = 1;
var_dump(!$cart = true || !$product = false || $quantity <= 0);
---------
Output : bool(false)
```

Why ? I was expected this to be `TRUE`

And why the following exact same condition output what I expected : `TRUE`

```
var_dump(false || true || false);
---------
Output : bool(true)
```

**EDIT**

I know that `=` is for assignement.
But doing this :

```
if(!$var = null){
  // $var is not empty
}
```

Is a way to assign a value and check if this value is `null|false|empty|array empty...` at the same time.

Comment: `=` is assignment, use `==` or `===` to check for equality.

Comment: I know that... But if null is asigned to a value, the result of this expression return false.

Comment: The assignment has a different operator precedence than the comparison, i.e. lower than the `||` operator.

Comment: No, in that snippet `$var` is still empty, you can check it with `var_dump`. And you would enter the condition because of [casting](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php#language.types.boolean.casting), `null` is a _false-y_ value and you are negating it. If `null` was a variable with a non-empty value it won't enter the condition, since it would evaluate to `if (false)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is about **operator precedence** and **associativity**.

```
var_dump(!$cart = true || !$product = false || $quantity <= 0);
```

is the same as

```
var_dump(!$cart = (true || !$product = false || $quantity <= 0));
```

Result of `(true || !$product = false || $quantity <= 0)` is true. `!true` is `false`.

Comment: Ok I see now... That's a verry stupid mistake of mine.
So I got to do that ``var_dump((!$cart = true) || (!$product = null) || ($quantity <= 0));``